# How to call some method when *ngIf condition fails in angular2 ?

Tags: angular

I have list (ul) and added ngIf condition on 5 list elements(li). They will be displayed when condition is met.I want to call some method when ngIf condition is met or fails. I have added directive on list element and calling my method in ngAfterViewInit(). But when condition fails , it is not called. Please suggest any way out. Here is my piece of code.

```
<ul class="choose-list">
<li filter-selection  (onWidthChange)="setfullWidth=$event" *ngIf="filter.country.name!=''"><span>{{filter.country.name}}</span><a (click)="onClearFilter('country')" href="#" class="mdi mdi-close"></a></li>
<li filter-selection  (onWidthChange)="setfullWidth=$event" *ngIf="filter.level.name!=''"><span>{{filter.level.name}}</span><a  (click)="onClearFilter('level')" href="#" class="mdi mdi-close"></a></li>
<li filter-selection (onWidthChange)="setfullWidth=$event" *ngIf="filter.institution.name!=''"><span>{{filter.institution.name}}</span><a (click)="onClearFilter('institution')" href="#" class="mdi mdi-close"></a></li>
<li filter-selection (onWidthChange)="setfullWidth=$event" *ngIf="filter.program.name!=''"><span>{{filter.program.name}}</span><a (click)="onClearFilter('program')" href="#" class="mdi mdi-close"></a></li>
<li filter-selection (onWidthChange)="setfullWidth=$event" *ngIf="filter.fromYear.name!=''"><span>{{filter.fromYear.name}}</span><a (click)="onClearFilter('fromYear')" href="#" class="mdi mdi-close"></a></li>
<li filter-selection (onWidthChange)="setfullWidth=$event" *ngIf="filter.toYear.name!=''"><span>{{filter.toYear.name}}</span><a (click)="onClearFilter('toYear')" href="#" class="mdi mdi-close"></a></li>
  </ul>

import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Input, Output , EventEmitter, Renderer } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({selector: '[filter-selection]'})
export class FilterSelectionDirective implements AfterViewInit  {

filteredElement; 
addBox; 
list; 
stretchBox;
holder;  


@Output() onWidthChange: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) {
    this.filteredElement = elementRef.nativeElement;

}


ngAfterViewInit() {
    let ctrl = this;
    this.addBox = this.filteredElement.parentElement.previousElementSibling;
    this.list = this.filteredElement.parentNode;
    this.holder = this.filteredElement.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    this.stretchBox = this.holder.firstElementChild;

    setTimeout(function () {
        ctrl.refreshWidth()
    }, 0);
}



refreshWidth() {
    debugger;
    var listWidth = 0;

    var items = this.filteredElement.parentElement.children; // all li

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        listWidth += $(items[i]).outerWidth(true);
    }
    console.log(listWidth);

    var newWidth;


    if (!items.length || $(this.addBox).outerWidth(true) + (listWidth + ($(this.list).outerWidth(true) - $(this.list).width())) > $(this.holder).width() * 0.7) {
        newWidth = '';
        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.stretchBox, 'width', newWidth);
        this.onWidthChange.emit(true);  //add full width
    }
    else {
        this.onWidthChange.emit(false);  //remove full width
        newWidth = Math.floor((100 - (($(this.addBox).outerWidth(true) + (listWidth +
            ($(this.list).outerWidth(true)
                - $(this.list).width()))) / $(this.holder).width() * 100)) /** 10*/) /*/ 10*/ + '%';

        this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.stretchBox, 'width', newWidth);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's a bad idea. Angular change detection will call these methods every time change detection is run, that's way more often than the condition will change between true/false. Change your model to emit events (for example using an `Observable` when properties change and then call your method from there.

Comment: Thanks ! The problem is when i call  refrehwidth() in clearFilters(), the list item is not removed yet from the DOM tree. ngIf rendering is done after clearFlter(). 
var items = this.filteredElement.parentElement.children;

Comment: You can inject `constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}` and call `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` after you remove an item to get the DOM updated immediately - I don't see an `*ngFor` though. Can't make much sense of your code. You should try to use more bindings instead of `renderer...`.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}
```

and call

```
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```

after you remove an item, to get the DOM updated immediately

Comment: When i added child component to this component, it gives exception "TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngDoCheck' of undefined".

Comment: Sorry, but that's not enough information. Are you calling `ngDoCheck` yourself somewhere?

Comment: No, When i comment this.cdRef.detectChanges(), then no exception occurs

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337021/typeerror-cannot-read-property-ngdocheck-of-undefined-in-angular2