# TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngDoCheck' of undefined in angular2

Tags: angular

In Child1 component, I have used `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` . But when I add Child2 component on the same parent component. Child2 component implements AfterViewInit . It gives me exception

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'ngDoCheck' of undefined in angular2.

Please suggest the solution.

```
child1:

export class MainFilterComponent implements AfterViewInit {

constructor(){
 this.cdRef.detectChanges();
}
}


Child2
export class MainCompareComponent implements AfterViewInit {
 constructor(){
 }
}




export class MainFilterComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  countries: Country[] = [];
  filterToggled: boolean = false;
  filter: Filter;
  fromYears: Option[] = [];
  holder: any;
  institutions: Institution[] = [];
  isFullWidth: boolean;
  levels: Option[] = [];
  programs: Program[] = [];
  toYears: Option[] = [];
  stretchBox: any;

  @ViewChild('addBox') addBox: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('chooselist') list: ElementRef;


  constructor(private translate: TranslateService, private filterService: FilterService, private zone: NgZone,
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router, private elementRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer, private cdRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    this.filter = filterService.getFilter();
    this.getCountries();
    this.getLevels();
    this.getInstitutions();
    this.getPrograms();
    this.getYears();
    this.updateFilterFromURL();
    this.filterService.onFilterChanged$.subscribe(filter => this.onFilterChanged(filter));
  }


  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    jQuery.getScript('./app/components/filter/main-filter.js');
    this.holder = this.list.nativeElement.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
    this.stretchBox = this.holder.firstElementChild;
  }


 onFilterChanged(filter: Filter) {
    this.filter = filter;
    this.cdRef.detectChanges();
   if (this.list.nativeElement.children.length > 0) {
     this.renderer.setElementClass(this.list.nativeElement, 'select', true);
   }
   else if (this.list.nativeElement.children.length === 0) {
     this.renderer.setElementClass(this.list.nativeElement, 'select', false);
   }
   this.refreshWidth();

  }


 refreshWidth() {
    var items = this.list.nativeElement.children;
    var listWidth = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      listWidth += $(items[i]).outerWidth(true);
    }
    var newWidth;
    if (!items.length || $(this.addBox.nativeElement).outerWidth(true) + (listWidth + ($(this.list.nativeElement).outerWidth(true) - $(this.list.nativeElement).width())) > $(this.holder).width() * 0.7) {
      newWidth = '';
      this.isFullWidth = true;
    }
    else {
      this.isFullWidth = false;
      newWidth = Math.floor((100 - (($(this.addBox.nativeElement).outerWidth(true) + (listWidth +
        ($(this.list.nativeElement).outerWidth(true)
          - $(this.list.nativeElement).width()))) / $(this.holder).width() * 100)) - 1 /** 10*/) /*/ 10*/ + '%';
    }
    this.renderer.setElementStyle(this.stretchBox, 'width', newWidth);
  }
```

Comment: How you have added the child component in parent component.

Comment: yes. If i remove the child2 MainCompareComponent  from the parent then it works fine.

Comment: You have imorted the Child2 component right? could you share the Parent component code alone.

Comment: <main-filter></main-filter>

<div class="open-close-add" main-compare>
        
      </div>

Comment: child1.ts file code

Comment: You can use import `MainCompareComponent  from './**your code location**'`

Comment: What's the point of calling `this.cdRef.detectChanges();` in the constructor?

Comment: Please check the code for MainFilterComponent . I am calling it on onFilterChanged() event

Comment: I have removed this.cdRef.detectChanges() from filter event and used somewhere else and it worked fine for me

Answer (score 0):

well I am not so sure but this may appear due to flexLayout used on material components so try to replace it with css framework